# A send and receive UDP node in C

Tags: c, pthreads, udp

I am working on a (personal) light weight distributed project for the Rpi platform.  Making it distributed requires P2P communication between the nodes, and I thought it would be a good time to learn sockets and UDP.

The end goal is to get to a point where nodes can do things like leader election, and distribute tasks between them through messages.

The below code uses `pthreads` to open two sockets; one sending and one receiving.  The receiving socket just prints the message it receives for now.

I compiled and ran this code on two docker containers and it works.  I am wondering about the following:

Since I can get the Hostname/IP of the sender, I can have a simple switch/if-else and take action based on the sender.

What message size is small enough so that packets of multiples senders are not mixed?

Also about the following sentence

> the networking stack will buffer up (a finite number of) incoming UDP
>   packets for you, so that (assuming you call recv() in a relatively
>   timely manner), no incoming packets should get lost

Does the code below satisfy this (assuming of course I've added a check on the Hostname/IP)?

If not, how should it be modified?  Would using `select/poll` inside the thread be better?

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 500

struct host
{
    char *node;
    char *port;
    char *msg;
};

int
create_socket(char *host, char *port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int sfd;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */

    if (host != NULL)
    {
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */    
    } else {
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */
        hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */
        hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
        hints.ai_addr = NULL;
        hints.ai_next = NULL;
    }

    int s = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
        Try each address until we successfully connect(2).
        If socket(2) (or connect(2)/bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
        and) try the next address. */
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        // printf("this is the socketaddr data %s\n", rp->ai_addr->sa_data[]);
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
                    rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (host == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", "host is null");
            if (bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0) /* server socket */
               break;                  /* Success */
        }
        else
        {
            if (connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1) /* client socket */
                break;                  /* Success */
        }

        close(sfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind/connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */

    return sfd;
}

void*
send_msg(void *arg)
{
    size_t len;
    struct host *receiver = (struct host *) arg;

    int sfd = create_socket(receiver->node, receiver->port);
    printf("sending sfd = %d\n", sfd);

    len = strlen(receiver->msg) + 1;

    /* +1 for terminating null byte */
    if (len + 1 > BUF_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Ignoring long message\n");
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("sending message %s\n", receiver->msg);
        if (write(sfd, receiver->msg, len) != len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "partial/failed write\n");
            close(sfd);
            sleep(1);
            sfd = create_socket(receiver->node, receiver->port);
        }
        sleep(5);
    }


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void*
recv_msg(void *arg)
{
    int s;
    ssize_t nread;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    socklen_t peer_addr_len;
    struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;
    struct host *me = (struct host *) arg;

    int sfd = create_socket(me->node, me->port);

    printf("receive sfd = %d\n", sfd);
    for (;;) {
        printf("ready to receive message\n");

        peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);

        nread = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0,
               (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_len);

        printf(">>> %d\n", nread);
        if (nread == -1)
            continue;               /* Ignore failed request */

        char host[NI_MAXHOST], service[NI_MAXSERV];

        s = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
                       peer_addr_len, host, NI_MAXHOST,
                       service, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV);
        if (s == 0)
            printf("Received %zd bytes from %s:%s\n",
                nread, host, service);
        else
           fprintf(stderr, "getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void
create_threads(struct host *me,struct host *receiver)
{
    pthread_t tids[2];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_create(&tids[0], &attr, send_msg, receiver);
    pthread_create(&tids[1], &attr, recv_msg, me);

    pthread_join(tids[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tids[1], NULL);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct host me;
    struct host receiver;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port msg...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    receiver.node = argv[1];
    receiver.port = argv[2];
    receiver.msg  = argv[3];

    me.node = NULL;
    me.port = argv[2];

    create_threads(&me, &receiver);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does the code below satisfy this (?)

Small review: minor issues.

1. `if (len + 1 > BUF_SIZE) {` looks off-by-1, in a bad direction.  I'd expect `if (len > BUF_SIZE) {` as `len` already includes space for the *null character*.
2. Code assumes `ssize_t` is `int` when printing.  Alternative:

   ```
   ssize_t nread;
   nread = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0,
          (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_len);
   // printf(">>> %d\n", nread);
   printf(">>> %lld\n", (long long) nread);
   // or
   printf(">>> %jd\n", (intmax_t) nread);
   ```

Comment: I mean: in the scenario where one node is managing the cluster, and is receiving more messages than the others, such that it is receiving many, many messages.  Will the above code handle a fast message rate? what happens when the rate is too fast?  what should be changed to handle that? (other than use TCP  to guarantee delivery :) )

Comment: @SamHammamy IDK about [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195766/a-send-and-receive-udp-node-in-c/195899#comment377235_195899).  Yet these are things about your code I could recognize that may fail and so not satisfy  overall functional goal.  Good luck.